# The JS Message container doesn't show error messages in the Payment checkout step

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, messages

Maybe due to our configuration (maybe due to M2), error messages are not printed anymore in Onepage checkout.

- It's a simple case of throwing a `\LocalizedException` during `capture()` for reason X. That results in a 400 response for the `/V1/carts/mine/payment-information` request. All good.
- M2 creates a JSON out of that exception, with a `message` property, which is then handled [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/b6bb8e57d83ce8eed5f91c724fee8f757ac3b979/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/place-order.js#L56). Superb.
- The error message is then pushed onto an error message container [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/b6bb8e57d83ce8eed5f91c724fee8f757ac3b979/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/frontend/web/js/model/messages.js#L41). Omg, brilliant.
- Then nothing happens, what.

I was expecting the error message to be printed. Mind you, the above behaviour was tracked down with a JS debugger, I'm not *assuming* it happens.

Trying to fix this, I've stumbled upon `\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface`. Using that in my `capture()` method, it correctly added another message which this time was fetched with that `customer/section/load` request I dearly hate. And, although the `messages` property of the response was what I wanted, I still couldn't see my message appear.

Ok...

Then I saw that, for checkout only, M2 [removes the messages container](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/b6bb8e57d83ce8eed5f91c724fee8f757ac3b979/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml#L434) in favour of [UI Components](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/b6bb8e57d83ce8eed5f91c724fee8f757ac3b979/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml#L34-L38). It was too simple, you see. They had to put JSON in HTML through a PHP-parsed XML.

If I put back that message block, the message is finally showing, hooray. But I don't think M2 devs removed that block by mistake.

Do any of you know how exactly the JS message container does its job? Who triggers its rendering?

Comment: I tracked that bit of code back to this commit on beta16: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/fe972aaba5ffa69be92da7bb1e4be03c61803958 -Not clear what duplication the commit refers to, though, or how it's supposed to work alternatively.

Comment: Did you ever solve this without modifying xml of checkout?

Comment: How did you put the message back?

Comment: It was a year ago. Who knows what I did then... Sorry.